# Need insert box for API

Tags: php

I am currently making API calls to Trade Me which is a New Zealand website.
Below is only part of the PHP code.

```
$access_post_data = '';
$watchlist = "https://api.tmsandbox.co.nz/v1/MyTradeMe/Watchlist/All.json";
$member_id = 4003274;
$feedback_url = "https://api.tmsandbox.co.nz/v1/Member/$member_id/Feedback/selling.json";
$baseString = "GET&" .rawurlencode($feedback_url) . '&';
```

Can someone please tell me how I can create an interface so that I can type the member id on the website without going in the code to change the $member_id.
So that the code will be changed through the website for others to search different members and not only me by going to the code.
If you can write an example code and how I can use it, I will be very thankful.
If you need to see more code, please let me know!
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is a PHP GET request.

e.g.

```
$access_post_data = '';
$watchlist = "https://api.tmsandbox.co.nz/v1/MyTradeMe/Watchlist/All.json";
$member_id = $_GET["memberid"]
$feedback_url = "https://api.tmsandbox.co.nz/v1/Member/$member_id/Feedback/selling.json";
$baseString = "GET&" .rawurlencode($feedback_url) . '&';
```

Form:

```
<form action="scriptname.php" method="get">
  MemberID: <input type="number" name="memberid"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I just want to know how I can make it on my website, so that I can type in the member_id that I want to look for instead of the fixed number in the code.

Comment: Thank you. I've done that. Can you show me how I can make a form so that I can use the $_GET["memberid"] please? Thanks!

Comment: i've updated the original answer to include the html form that will work. Hopefully that answers your question :)